# (Autohotkey) need help for selecting different Excel cell with "+1" thingy.. or i don't know how to call it

Tags: autohotkey

i need help in Excel automation with autohotkey..

So i want to select "A1" cell in the 1st input, then for the 2nd, 3rd, and next input, i want to select the "A" cell +1,
so the "A" cell selected in the 2nd INPUT will be A2
the "A" cell selected in the 3nd INPUT will be A3, etc...

So it will be likely like this..

```
INPUT1:
X=1

oExcel := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Sheets("SHEET").Activate
oExcel.Range("A1").Select

goto, INPUTX:

INPUTX:
X = +1
oExcel := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
oExcel.Sheets("SHEET").Activate
oExcel.Range("A(X)").Select
```

but i don't know how to write it properly in AHK codes.... can somebody help me to solve this please? Thankyou very much...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No worries, you were almost there. I think this is what you want. You'll likely want to loop and you also need to concat the numbers into the cell name

```
DoMyStuff:
/* You only need to get the Excel COM object once. 
 * So we do this here, outside of the loop. */
oExcel := ComObjActive("Excel.Application")
; activate the sheet once.
oExcel.Sheets("SHEET").Activate

Loop, 100 ; this repeats the following code from 1 to 100.
{
    /* A_Index in a "Loop" block becomes 1..2..3.. 
     * to 100 (each loop pass) or whatever is set above. 
     * With AHK v1.1, you can concat like so: 
     * "something" 42 "anotherthing"
     * gives
     * "something42anotherthing"
     */
    oExcel.Range("A" A_Index).Select 
}
return
```

Comment: thankyou very much for helping me out Joe, you can read my mind. Really appreciate it. Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help!